# How to send image in nodemailer and put it as background image in html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, nodemailer

I am trying to send personalized emails to gmail, which I want to have a background image and some logos, the problem is that I send only two images (logo and a landscape), these are in png format, the logo if you load it as an image , but the background image is sending it to me as a downloadable file.I'm using pug.

My code:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const pug = require('pug');
const path = require('path');
const excel = require('../../public/scripts/readExcel');

const image_path = path.join(__dirname + '../../../img/','logo.png');
const image_ground_path = path.join(__dirname + '../../../img/','backGround.png');
const path_Excel = path.join(__dirname + '../../../config/BD/emails.xlsx');

let dateObj = new Date();
let year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();


exports.sendEmail = ()=>{

    try {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            let dataExcel =  excel.readExcel(path_Excel);

            if(dataExcel.length >0){
                const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    // host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
                    // port: 2525,
                    // auth: {
                    // user: "",
                    // pass: ""
                    // },
                    // tls:{
                    //     rejectUnauthorized: false
                    // }

                    service:'gmail',
                    host: "smtp.gmail.com",//host de mi servidor
                    port: 587,
                    secure:false,
                    auth:{
                        user:"mygmail@gmail.com",
                        pass:"*****"
                    },
                });
                for (let index = 0; index < dataExcel.length; index++) {
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    pug.renderFile(__dirname + "../../../views/index.pug", { name: dataExcel[index].name, img:'',img2:'',route:image_ground_path, year, area: dataExcel[index].area }, function (err, data) {
                    
           
                        let template = pug.compile(data);
                    

                        const replacements = {
                            img: "cid:logo",
                            img2: "cid:backGroundImg"
                        };
                        
                    
                    
                        const mainOptions = {
                            from: "mygmail@gmail.com",
                            to: "person1.com",
                            subject: "Hello",
                            html: template(replacements),
                            attachments:[
                                {
                                    filename: 'logo-U.png',
                                    path: image_path,
                                    cid: 'logo'
                                },
                                {
                                    filename: 'backGround.png',
                                    path: image_ground_path,
                                    cid: 'backGroundImg'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        transporter.sendMail(mainOptions, function (err, info) {
                                if (err) {
    
                                    reject(err.message);
                                } else {
                                    resolve("Email(s) send(s) ");
                                    
                                }
                            });
                        
                        
                    }); 
                    
                    
                }
            }
            else{
                resolve("No emails sent");
            }
               
        })
        

    } catch (error) {
        
        return error;
    }
    

  

}
```

Here is a small snippet of my pug code:

```
  tr
      td
        div(style='background-color:#082CAF;color:white;padding:10px;border-radius:10px 10px 0 0')
          table(width='100%' align='center' cellpadding='0')
            tbody
              tr
                td(width='10%' height='70')
                  img(src="#{img}")
                  
                td(width='80%' height='70' style='color:white;text-align:center;font-size:25px')
                  strong General Directorate of Services

    tr
      td
        div(style='background-color:#ecf0f5;padding:10px;')
          table(width='100%' cellpadding='0' style='margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:40px')
            tbody
              tr
                td(width='10%')
                td(width='60%')
                  div(style='padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;border:0.5px solid #e5e5e5;margin-top:20px;border-radius:2px;background-image:url(#{img2});background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:center;background-size: 100% 100%;')
                    br
                    p(style='font-size:20px;text-align:center')
                      strong Dear) #{name}.
                    br
```

As you can see in a div, I have the background-image: url (), but it doesn't work for me, more than the first image, which is the logo.

Comment: The variable `img2` in index.pug has been rendered as an empty string `''` in the `pug.renderFile()` method. This variable does not exist anymore in the input to `pug.compile()`, and therefore your `replacements` values are not used. The `options` parameter of `pug.renderFile()` contains a few other spurious parameters such as `route`, `year`, `area` which are not in the pug file. You might want to clean this up.

Comment: @OldGeezer And how to send the images? if I have to remove the data from area, img2, route.

Comment: Can you provide two sample rows of the Excel data, like: `dataExcel = [ { name: "...", ...}, { "name: "...", ... }];` so that I can try and work out an answer.